# Showing $f(x_0) = f(x_0 + a)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,2a] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f(0) = f(2a)$. Show that there exists $x_0 \in [0,a]$ such that $f(x_0) = f(x_0 + a)$.

Anyone have ideas on this? Maybe I can say: Suppose not; then there exist $x_0 \in [0,a]$ s.t. $f(x_0) \neq f(x_0 + a)$. i.e., $f(x_0) - f(x_0 + a) \neq 0$. This makes me think we should use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there actually is some zero such that $g(x) = f(x_0) - f(x_0 + a) = 0$.

Comment: One way to think of this as having $f$ defined on a circle and look at the difference of the values of $f$ evaluated at antipodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.  We can define
\begin{equation*}
g(x)=f(x)-f(x+a)
\end{equation*}
and note that
\begin{align*}
g(0) &= f(0) - f(a)\\
g(a) &= f(a) - f(2a).
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{equation*}
g(0)+g(a) = f(0)-f(2a) = 0.
\end{equation*}

This last equation means that either $g(0)=g(a)=0$ or $g(0)$ and $g(a)$ have opposite signs.  In either case, the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that there is a value $x \in [0,a]$ such that $g(x)=0$, and thus that $f(x)-f(x+a)=0$.

Comment: Ah. So close. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Sure thing!  You had the right idea.